# Get single post id from json file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is maybe real easy, don´t know. But i´ve only done this with a node/express backend.
But not quite surt how to do this, only with frontend and a json file, where my data is.
Right now it shows a list of all my posts, but i want to get the unique post:id when clicking on a button.

A simple posts.json file:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Simple title1',
  content: 'Sample content...',
  permalink: 'simple-title1',
  author: 'Peter',
  datePublished: '2012-04-04'
 }, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'Simple title2',
  content: 'Sample content...',
  permalink: 'simple-title2',
  author: 'Peter',
  datePublished: '2012-05-04'
 }, {
   id: 3,
  title: 'Simple title3',
  content: 'Sample content...',
  permalink: 'simple-title3',
       author: 'Thomas',
  datePublished: '2012-06-04'
}]
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider




.state('home', {
    url: '/posts',
    templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
    controller: function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('posts.json')
    .success(function(data){
    $scope.posts = data;
    });
    }
})

          .state('viewdetails',{
    url:'/posts/:id/:permalink',
    templateUrl: 'view_details.html',
    controller: function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('source.json')
   //get a single post here???
    } }
```

And some of the code in my partial-home.html

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:50px">
  <!--row left-->
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-5  box-background" ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <!--column 1 left-->
    <div class="col-md-4 img-space">
      <img class="img-circle" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="{{prov.picture}}" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4>{{post.author}}</h4>
      <p class="text-grey">
        {{post.content}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <a ui-sref="posts/:id" class="btn btn-primary btn-color" style="width:100%">View details</a>
  </div>
  <!--end column 1 left-->
</div>
<!--end row left-->
```

I know this isn´t in a mvc pattern, but just want to do it really simple.
Have only done this before with a mongoose, node backend. So hope for some ideas help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would use $routeParams to get the id from your route and then use that as a variable in your $http request url. 
When fetching the same sourse.json file you can use that id to only assign the correct post to your view variable

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams